# How to format a esriFieldTypeDate parameter in a json url query to an ESRI REST server

Tags: json, rest, arcgis

I'm trying to query this API, filtering by the `RptDt` field, which is type `esriFieldTypeDate`.

The basic query looks like this:

```
https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
```

It's easy to filter a numeric variable like `POS_CUM_SUM` like so:

```
"https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=%20(POS_CUM_CP%20%3D%200%20OR%20POS_CUM_CP%20%3D%2010)%20&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json"
```

I can't figure out how to format the minimum and maximum arguments for the date field `RptDt`.

- because the attributes of `RptDt` are formatted as unix timestamps: 1642255200000, 1642428000000. But that returns error code 400.

```
https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=%20(RptDt%20%3D%20'1642255200000'%20OR%20RptDt%20%3D%20'1642428000000')%20&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
```

- Then, I noticed that the field length for `RptDt` is 8, so I tried rounding the unix timestamp to 8 digits (16422552, 16424280), but that also gives error code 400.
- I tried using YYYYMMDD format  (20210101 to 20211231), this **didn't** give an error, but the response has no features. Most of the dates do fall this period.

```
https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=%20(RptDt%20%3D%20%2720210101%27%20OR%20RptDt%20%3D%20%2720211231%27)%20&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
```

I haven't been able to find a solution in the [ArcGIS REST APIs](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) documentation. Does anyone understand what's missing from my queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. This query works. The relevant bit is `where=RptDt>'2022-01-01'`.

```
https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=RptDt>'2022-01-01'&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json
```

Thanks to [JamieKelly1 at the Esri Community Forum for answering this question](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-rest-api-questions/how-to-format-a-esrifieldtypedate-parameter-in-a/m-p/1134569#M4066).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling upon this one after getting the -2147220985 (which btw means bad SQL query), the full url I used had to contain Date before the actual date like so `Date'2015-02-02'` not just `'2015-02-02'`. Also, you cannot use epoch timestamp in miliseconds in the query builder (at least not for open data dc).

Example url:
`https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/ServiceRequests/MapServer/6/query?where=%20(ADDDATE%20%3D%20Date'2015-02-02'%20OR%20ADDDATE%20%3D%20Date'2015-02-03')%20&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json`

To search between two dates:
`https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/ServiceRequests/MapServer/6/query?where=ADDDATE BETWEEN DATE '2015-01-09 00:00:00' AND DATE '2015-01-09 12:00:00'&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json`

Comment: Great answer.  Is there a way to retrieve the date in the same 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?  Otherwise, the response needs to convert the unix date format.